# useState not returning data from fetch request

Tags: reactjs

Trying to figure out why the state is not being set after I fetch the data. Here is the code I am using...

```
const [data, setData]: any = useState({ items: [] });

useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
        const repsonse: any = await fetch('https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=react');
        const result: any = await repsonse.json();
        //console.log(result);
        setData(result.hits);
    }
    fetchData();
}, []);

console.log(data);
```

In the example above I am using hooks for useState(). Then I use a useEffect to do a fetch request. I use the setData function to set the state that I got from the request.

But when I console.log the data I get an empty array. Anyone know why this is happening? Might be something simple that I am missing.

Comment: Remove `await` from `await repsonse.json();`

Comment: Your code is asynchronous so data is empty at the time of the logging. Put the `console.log` right after `setData`.

Comment: The code looks correct!

Comment: @ravibagul91 await should be there, as `response.json()` is indeed a promise as well. What does the result say? Any errors in your console? Add a try/catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

useEffect is run after the render happens and since you initially your state is empty the console.log outside of `useEffect` will show you the empty data itself. However, once the data is fetched you will see the updated data in the second render. Also, you need to setState to items instead of directly passing the obtained list

```
const { useState, useEffect } = React;
const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({ items: [] });

  useEffect(() => {
      async function fetchData() {
          const repsonse= await fetch('https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=react');
          const result = await repsonse.json();
          //console.log(result);
          setData({items: result.hits});
      }
      fetchData();
  }, []);

  console.log(data);
     return <pre>{JSON.stringify(data.items null, 4)}</pre>

}
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-rubin-u1v88)

Comment: Ahh I see. I thought that useEffect happens before the render is called but I guess not. Also was using setData wrong. Thanks for the help!